# Listing a dictionary without using for loop

Tags: python, list

I have this dictionary output and wants to extract a certain key "e.g: HolderJob" into list without using for loop?

```
{u'RecipeName': u'APC_14A_COC_Al2O3_Fill-TEST', u'PalletPosition': u'1', u'IsSPC': u'N', u'Holder': u'23002154-1', u'PalletName': u'12', u'IsControl': u'N', u'LoadPosition': u'5', u'RunNumber': u'4613', u'ProcessToolName': u'DLCX01', u'MeasurementType': u'XRF', u'HolderJob': u'243340545'}
{u'RecipeName': u'APC_14A_COC_Al2O3_Fill-TEST', u'PalletPosition': u'1', u'IsSPC': u'N', u'Holder': u'23002158-1', u'PalletName': u'12', u'IsControl': u'N', u'LoadPosition': u'9', u'RunNumber': u'4613', u'ProcessToolName': u'DLCX01', u'MeasurementType': u'XRF', u'HolderJob': u'243340544'}
```

Current Code:

```
aList=[]
for palletload in  a['XMLSchemaPalletLoadTechData']['TechDataParams']:
        aList.append(palletload['HolderJob'])
print aList
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as it's function :

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter('HolderJob'), a['XMLSchemaPalletLoadTechData']['TechDataParams'])
>>> [u'243340545', u'243340544']
```

Comment: great! answer thanks for the fast response.

i have another solution kindly check if also good interms of speed.
    aList = [int(palletload['HolderJob']) for palletload in newpaldt['XMLSchemaPalletLoadTechData']['TechDataParams']]
 print aList